# How to create copy of telegram modal scrolling

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog, tailwind-css, css-animations

Telegram uses modals for some menus:

[image]

The point I stack in is if content of modal menu goes beyond the screen modal became scrollable but in not usual way.

Not content scrolling but rather part of modal.

What I mean is :

**before scrolling to bottom:**

[image]

**after scrolling to bottom:**

[image]

as you can see modal no longer goes to bottom edge of screen

if someone know how to implement this Iil be glad.

you can use tailwind , framer motion in explanation if want <3